# Sprite::createWithTexture with Rect not working as expected

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to build a sprite from an image. Using Image and Texture2D class and then later creating a sprite from the texture2D.

The image I am loading is 512x512 and I expected both versions of the createWithTexture to behave the same but they don't. Here the code:

```
Image* image = new Image();
image->initWithImageFile(fileName);

Texture2D* texture = new Texture2D();
texture->initWithImage(image);

//If used this way everything works as expected
Sprite* spr= Sprite::createWithTexture(texture);
//If used with a Rect weird result occurrs.
Sprite* spr= Sprite::createWithTexture(texture,Rect(0,0,512,512));
spr->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
spr->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));
spr->setScale(1.0f,1.0f);
this->addChild(spr);
```

Here the result of the first one using a Rect:

[image]

And here the Second version without a Rect:

[image]

Do anybody know what is happening? I need to use the method that uses the rect because I will be creating a bunch of sprites from this image in the future.

Edit1: After debugging both versions of the sprite. I have noticed that the one created without the Rect shows a rect of 0,0,240,240. Instead of 0,0,512,512 as I provided. Why 240?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was happening. Cocos2D-x uses director->setContentScaleFactor and glview->setDesignResolutionSize as a way to make things easier for multi resolution/device games. When you build the Rect to get a part (or full) texture you must have into account the CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() macro, in order to get correct target coordinates.

This can be checked at this link: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If your `vecSize` is bigger than the image's size, the image will be out of shape.
So if you don't know the image's real size, don't set it.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a valid answer. This was a cut down example where I will need to create some sprites from this image. So, I need the Rect version of the method.

Comment: can you tell me your glview screen size?

Comment: 960x640 in the device I'm currently checking

Comment: i did a test,finally know why,your device screen size is 640*960,but cocos2d seted it to be 320 * 640, and contentScale is 2.0,so your image size bacame 240

Comment: It all depends on the logical screen you configured and the target screen resolution. The resource design resolution has plays an important role too. Have a look at the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: check your source file,find this code                                                                                         `cc.Director:getInstance():getOpenGLView():setDesignResolutionSize(480, 320, 1)`
   ` cc.Director:getInstance():setContentScaleFactor(2.0)`
and set it to be  960*640    and 1.0  ,my code is lua ,you must write it use c++